# How to import CSV file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sqlite, csv, import

I want to import a CSV File (comma delimited with double quote) into SQLite using PowerShell script. I tried:

```
echo ".import export.csv mytable" | sqlite3.exe
```

I get this error:

> export.csv:327: unescaped " character

I get this error for all lines. On SQLite's command line shell same command works:

```
sqlite > .import export.csv mytable
```

How can I make this command work using a PowerShell script?

Comment: You may not need the `echo` (which is really an alias for `Write-Output`) in PowerShell; try `".import export.csv mytable" | sqlite3.exe`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I got same error!

Comment: Is the "327" in the error message supposed to represent a line number in the file, or is it an error code that sqlite is reporting? If it is a line number, how many lines does the file have - and how many lines are getting imported when you do it manually?

Comment: If I remember correctly you need to run it like this: `sqlite3 yourdatabase.db < ".import export.csv mytable"`

Comment: @JamesC. `The '<' operator is reserved for future use.`

Comment: Ah, `<` redirection isn't supported in PowerShell then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following single command line works in both

- `cmd.exe` (version 10.0.x.x via `ver`) and
- `powershell.exe` (version 5.1.x.x via `$PSVersionTable`)

```
.\sqlite3.exe my.db ".import file1.csv table1 --csv"
```

This loads the contents of csv file `file1.csv` into table `table1` within the sqlite database file `my.db`. The `--csv` flag will import the file and create the table structure based on the header column names in that file, and will approximately infer the data types.

You can import multiple files this way.
i.e.

```
.\sqlite3.exe my.db ".import file1.csv table1 --csv" ".import file2.csv table2 --csv"
```

You can chain commands together to immediately open the database for querying by appending `; .\sqlite3.exe my.db`.

i.e.

```
.\sqlite3.exe my.db ".import file1.csv table1 --csv" ".import file2.csv table2 --csv; .\sqlite3.exe my.db"
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in both PowerShell 5.1 and v7.0.

```powershell
$params = @"
.mode csv
.separator ,
.import export.csv mytable
"@

$params | .\sqlite3.exe mydatabase.db
```

Answer (score 0):

what about sqlite3.exe ".import export.csv mytable".

You can check the documentation of sqlite3.exe to use it not being in its shell, how to pass parameter to sqlite3.exe.

You can try below line

```
Invoke-Expression 'sqlite3 yourdatabase.db < ".import export.csv mytable"'
```